# Why ionic spinner doesn't show up in my project?

Tags: ionic-framework

I add a spinner icon in my ionic project, but it doesn't up. I have tried to place the ionic-spinner item in different place in the html file, but it doesn't work. Can you help me to solve this problem?

HTML:

```html
<ion-content>
   <form (submit)="doLogin()">
    <ion-list>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label fixed>{{ 'EMAIL' | translate }}</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="account.email" name="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label fixed>{{ 'PASSWORD' | translate }}</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="account.password" name="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <div padding>
        <button ion-button color="primary" block>{{ 'LOGIN_BUTTON' | translate }}</button>
      </div>

    </ion-list>
  </form>

  <ion-spinner name="lines"></ion-spinner>

</ion-content>
```

SCSS:

```scss
page-login {
  ion-spinner {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    stroke: #444;
    fill: #222;
  }
}
```

Comment: which ionic version?

Comment: Hi, I've tried your code and it works Fine and the spinner is also showing. So, can you please give us some more Info to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks. It works after I change name to "bubbles"